# How to make the entire area of a <box> in XUL clickable?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

Trying to learn a bit of XUL but am a bit stuck. Building a very basic album list to start.

So say I have this box - the song list starts hidden but I want to show it when I click on the main `albuminfo` box.

```
<box align="left" class="album"  id="test" orient="vertical">
    <box class="albumInfo" ><description value="Album 1" class="albumName"/><label class="albumArtist" value="Album artist 1"/></box>
    <box><label value="Year of release"/><label value="Genre"/></box>

    <listbox align="left" class="songlist" collapsed="true">
        <listitem label="Song 1"/>
        <listitem label="Song 2"/>
        <listitem label="Song 3"/>
        <listitem label="Song 3"/>
        <listitem label="Song 5"/>
    </listbox>
</box>
```

How can I fire a Javascript command when I click the entire `albuminfo` box area? I can use a button just fine, but I really want to make the entire box area clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it many ways in XUL. SInce you asked a simple way doing it by clicking a button, here you go:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<box align="left" class="album"  id="test" orient="vertical">
    <box class="albumInfo" ><description value="Album 1" class="albumName"/>
<label class="albumArtist" value="Album artist 1"/>
</box>
    <box><label value="Year of release"/><label value="Genre"/></box>

    <listbox align="left" class="songlist" collapsed="true" id="listBox" >
        <listitem label="Song 1"/>
        <listitem label="Song 2"/>
        <listitem label="Song 3"/>
        <listitem label="Song 3"/>
        <listitem label="Song 5"/>
    </listbox>
</box>
<row><button label="Album Info" oncommand="Open();"/> </row>

<script type="application/x-javascript">
<![CDATA[
   function Open()
{
document.getElementById('listBox').setAttribute("collapsed", "false");

}

]]>
</script>

</window>
```

When you click the button you will get your Album Info!!!

If not, you can use this option, when you click anywhere on the box, you listbox will open, by changing above slightly.

```
<box align="left" class="album"  id="test" orient="vertical" onclick="OpenInfo()">

function OpenInfo()
{
alert('hi');
document.getElementById('listBox').setAttribute("collapsed", "false");

}
```

You can manipulate list in many ways. For more reference please check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Manipulating_Lists

Answer (score 0):

The user can trigger the `command` event in XUL by multiple means. For example: click the element with the mouse, press a default hotkey (<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> for a button) when focus is on the element, click the element's *label*, press the element's or element label's access key. From the sound of your question, you are really only interested in mouse clicks on the element itself and you don't need all the additional accessibility provided by the `command` event. Which means that you can simply listen to the `click` event:

```
<box class="albumInfo" onclick="...">
```

You could for example trigger an existing `<command>` element if the element is clicked:

```
<box class="albumInfo" onclick="document.getElementById('album-info-command').doCommand();">
```